# What does |>> do in shell?

Tags: shell

Got from this [meme](https://www.facebook.com/nixcraft/photos/a.431194973560553/4020109624669052/), but nobody answer when I commented (also googled but not found)

[image: got from this meme]

Comment: nothing, they are two different operators pipe `|` and append redirection `>>`

Comment: Based on the comments from the Facebook page, it's more of a joke of people running commands like `grep -E file | sed s/<regex>/thing/g' | awk <expression> >> output`.. where they are piping inputs together where it may not be necessary

Answer (score 4):

```
rm /tmp/output 2>/dev/null || :

grep nobody /etc/passwd | sed -e 's/:.*//' >>/tmp/output
grep nobody /etc/passwd |>>/tmp/output sed -e 's/:.*//'

cat /tmp/output  # should be two "nobody" lines
```

The two `grep …|sed …` pipelines are exactly equivalent, showing that `|>>` is not special for the *nix shell, just the `|` (pipe) and `>>` (append-to-file) operators concatenated. Redirection can be placed anywhere in a command.

Comment: correct, but this has nothing to explain what `|>>` is, except that you pointed `>>` can be placed in everywhere in a command while talking on `|>>` that cannot be `grep …. | sed … |>>`. but you explains only  `>>`. so there is no single `|>>` operator AFAIK. and depending of where those are used they can be `bitwise OR |` or `right bitwise shift >>` in bash

Comment: Although *may* is a considerable distance from *is unhelpful*.

Comment: @αғsнιη The key distinction is that they are two different operators that (apparently) do not require whitespace to separate them syntactically (which is untrue of many other operators).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, operators mostly don't need white space around them, `(cat -n<foo>bar&echo b)` works just fine. The exception being when without whitespace the whole thing would look like another operator, e.g. `cat < <(echo foo)` works but `cat <<(echo foo)` gives a syntax error (in Bash and ksh; Zsh deals with that ok). And before someone says `[` and `[[`, they not operators, but a regular command and a shell keyword.

Comment: -1 this answer doesn't explain what the `|>>` actually does.

Comment: I mentioned that `|` (pipe) and `>>` (append-to-file) operators in this case are two separate operators that don't need whitespace between them; using `|` (bitwise-or) and `>>` (right-shift) this way cannot be done since they are two-operand infix operators.

Comment: ~@ilkkachu Some do and some don't need spaces. But why try to remember all the cases, at the risk of getting it wrong? Making code hard to read compounds the fact that it is hard to write: the very existence of this thread is enough proof.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, these are equivalent

```bsh
echo foo |>> file rev
echo foo | rev >> file
```

But the `>` redirection is a bit different: if you use `set -o noclobber` to protect against accidentally truncating files

```bsh
$ rm file
$ echo foo |>> file rev
$ cat file
oof
$ echo bar |> file rev
bash: file: cannot overwrite existing file
$ cat file
oof
```

In that case you use `>|` to purposefully overwrite the file, leading to this charming command

```bsh
$ echo bar |>| file rev
$ cat file
rab
```